# Conectar y hacer peticiones desde base de datos para una aplicacion android

Tags: java, sql, base-de-datos

Hola tengo una aplicacion en android donde quiero hacer conexiones en base de datos, me base en esta serie de videos [youtube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-usS3_-zWVg&t=2s), mi aplicacion funciona, pero al momento de apretar cualqiuer boton, ya sea para iniciar sesion o registrar a un usuario no funciona, al parecer ni siquiera intenta conectarse.

Al forzar el php de registro dandole strings, los registra pero quiero hacerlo desde la aplicacion con edit text y no funciona como que los parametros no se mandan.

[image: Captura de php registro]

[image: Captura de php login]

Al momento de acceder desde navegador si me funciona solo que pide los parametros que se mandan desde la aplicacion.

Si tengo la linea de permisos de internet en el manifest
de igual manera la libreria volley en la version 1.1.0

Aqui es donde se hace el request de registro.

```
package com.example.login;

import com.android.volley.Response;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.StringRequest;

import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

public class RegisterRequest extends StringRequest {

    private static final String REGISTER_REQUEST_URL="http://10.213.70.238:80/Register.php";
    private Map<String,String> params;
    public RegisterRequest(String name, String username, int age, String password, Response.Listener<String> listener) {
        super(Method.POST,REGISTER_REQUEST_URL,listener,null);
        params=new HashMap<>();
        params.put("name",name);
        params.put("username",username);
        params.put("age",age+"");
        params.put("password",password);
    }
    @Override
    public Map<String,String> getParams() {
        return params;
    }
}
```

Y aquí donde se hace toda la captura de datos.

```
package com.example.login;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AlertDialog;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import com.android.volley.RequestQueue;
import com.android.volley.Response;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.Volley;

import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;


public class Registro extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener {

    EditText etnombre, etusuario, etpassword, etedad;
    Button btn_registrar;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_registro);

        etnombre = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.et_Registro_Nombre);
        etusuario = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.et_Registro_Usuario);
        etpassword = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.et_Registro_Contrasena);
        etedad= (EditText) findViewById(R.id.et_Registro_Edad);

        btn_registrar = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_Registro_Registrar);
        btn_registrar.setOnClickListener(this);


    }


    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {

        final String name= etnombre.getText().toString();
        final String username= etusuario.getText().toString();
        final String password= etpassword.getText().toString();
        final int age =  Integer.parseInt(etedad.getText().toString());

        Response.Listener<String> respoListener = new Response.Listener<String>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(String response) {
                try {
                    JSONObject jsonResponse = new JSONObject(response);
                    boolean success = jsonResponse.getBoolean("success");

                    if(success)
                    {
                        Intent intent= new Intent(Registro.this, MainActivity.class);
                        Registro.this.startActivity(intent);
                        //startActivity(intent);
                    }
                    else{
                        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(Registro.this);
                        builder.setMessage("Error de Registro")
                                .setNegativeButton("Retry", null)
                                .create().show();
                    }
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

            }
        };
    RegisterRequest registerRequest= new RegisterRequest(name, username, age, password, respoListener);
        RequestQueue queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(Registro.this);
        queue.add(registerRequest);
    }
}
```

Aqui es el request del login

```
package com.example.login;

import com.android.volley.Request;
import com.android.volley.Response;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.StringRequest;

import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

public class LoginRequest extends StringRequest {

    private static final String LOGIN_REQUEST_URL = "http://10.213.70.238:80/Login.php";
    private Map<String, String> params;

    public LoginRequest(String username, String password, Response.Listener<String> listener) {
        super(Request.Method.POST, LOGIN_REQUEST_URL, listener, null);
        params = new HashMap<>();
        params.put("username", username);
        params.put("password", password);
    }

    @Override
    public Map<String, String> getParams() {
        return params;
    }
}
```

Y en el main se procesa todo lo demas

```
package com.example.login;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AlertDialog;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.android.volley.RequestQueue;
import com.android.volley.Response;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.Volley;

import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    TextView tv_Registrar;
    Button btn_Login;
    EditText et_Username;
    EditText et_Password;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        tv_Registrar = (findViewById(R.id.tv_Main_Registrar));
        btn_Login =(findViewById(R.id.btn_Main_IniciarSesion));
        et_Username = (findViewById(R.id.et_Main_Usuario));
        et_Password = (findViewById(R.id.et_Main_Contrasena));

        tv_Registrar.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent intentReg= new Intent(MainActivity.this,Registro.class);
                MainActivity.this.startActivity(intentReg);
            }
        });

        btn_Login.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                final String username = et_Username.getText().toString();
                final String password = et_Password.getText().toString();
                Response.Listener<String> responseListener = new Response.Listener<String>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(String response) {
                        try {
                            JSONObject jsonResponse = new JSONObject(response);
                            boolean success = jsonResponse.getBoolean("success");
                            if (success){
                                String name = jsonResponse.getString("name");
                                int age = jsonResponse.getInt("age");

                                Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this,Usuario.class);
                                intent.putExtra("name",name);
                                intent.putExtra("username",username);
                                intent.putExtra("password",password);
                                intent.putExtra("age",age);

                                MainActivity.this.startActivity(intent);

                            }else {
                                AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this);
                                builder.setMessage("error inicio de sesion")
                                        .setNegativeButton("Retry",null)
                                        .create().show();
                            }
                        } catch (JSONException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }
                };

                LoginRequest loginRequest = new LoginRequest(username,password,responseListener);
                RequestQueue queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(MainActivity.this);
                queue.add(loginRequest);
            }


        });
    }
}
```

El problema en si creo que es al momento de conectarse. Lo he tratado desde emulador de android y desde un celular conectado. Se siente que los botones no hacen nada.

Comment: ¿Depuraste con `Log` si los datos están pasando de los EditText a la parte donde mandas los datos al servidor? Es lo primero que hay que  revisar.

Comment: Dos cosas que debes considerar: 1. Android para persistencia (de manera local) trabaja con SQLite. 2. Si necesitas integrarte con una base de datos como Oracle, SQLServer, PostgreSQL, etc. lo recomendable es que crees un API Rest el cual se consuma desde la aplicacion android.

Comment: @A.Cedano si en el debug si entran los datos pero al parecer el request es lo que no se manda

Comment: Pues lo mismo, tienes que hacer debug de `response` dentro del `onResponse()`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yo lo que hago para consultar a una base de datos es rescatar un Json que se obtiene desde la pagina la cual procesa los datos, en este caso seria la respuesta de http://10.213.70.238:80/Register.php... para ello utilizo "A[ndroid Asynchronous Http Client](https://loopj.com/android-async-http/)".

Te dejo un ejemplo de como yo recibo algunos datos: 
Primero que nada debes importar la libreria en tu clase

```
import com.loopj.android.http.*;
```

Luego ejecutamos el codigo para consultar segun tu direccion url:

```
    private void consultarTipoMuestra(){
    String url3 = urlip+"TipoMuestra?RUT="+rutS;
    cliente.get(url3, new AsyncHttpResponseHandler() {
        @Override
        public void onSuccess(int statusCode, Header[] headers, byte[] responseBody) {
            //En esta linea enviamos la respuesta como un responseBody a otro metodo para rescatar los datos.
            rellenarSpinnerTipoMuestra(new String(responseBody));
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(int statusCode, Header[] headers, byte[] responseBody, Throwable error) {

        }
    });
}
```

Esta accion me devuelve como Json lo siguiente:
[{"SAMPLE_TYPE":"AGUAS"},{"SAMPLE_TYPE":"ALIMENTO"}]

Procedemos a rescatar los datos que necesitamos:

```
        //Recibimos la respuesta como String que viene del proceso anterior
    private void rellenarSpinnerTipoMuestra(String respuesta){
    //Generamos una nueva lista para obtener todos los datos que se encuentren dentro del JSOn
    listaTMuestra = new ArrayList<String>();
    listaTMuestra.add("Seleccione");
    try {
        //Convertimos el JSOn a un nuevo JSOnArray
        JSONArray jsonTMuestra = new JSONArray(respuesta);
        //Recorremos el JSON
        for (int i = 0; i<jsonTMuestra.length();i++){
        //Añadimos los datos que se encuentran dentro del JSON como "SAMPLE_TYPE" a 
        //una variable previamente definida.                
      listaTMuestra.add(jsonTMuestra.getJSONObject(i).getString("SAMPLE_TYPE"));
        }
        //En mi caso utilice los datos obtenidos para rellenar un Spinner.
         ArrayAdapter<String> r = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, 
       android.R.layout.simple_dropdown_item_1line,listaTMuestra);
        spTipoMuestra.setAdapter(r);
        rescatarTipoProducto();
    }catch(Exception e1){
        e1.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Al momento de entregarle los datos a una variable ya puedes utilizarlo para lo que necesites. Si tienes solamente un dato como respuesta de tu consulta en PHP no es necesario utilizar una lista.

Comment: Gracias por responder lo probare, no sabes si hay manera de mandar datos para validar un login?

Comment: En el onClick del boton obtienes los datos que ingresa el usuario y lo envias dentro de la URL para consultarlo mediante tu codigo PHP en la base de datos, seria algo asi: http://miproyecto/consultarusuario.php?user=txtuser&&pass=txtpass. Con esto obtendrias una respuesta en el JSON la cual puedes consultar dependiendo si encuentra el usuario o no.

Comment: No puedo abrir el ejemplo de tu proyecto.

Comment: es solamente un ejemplo, yo no se como tienes programado tu PHP o que respuesta entrega, en ese caso se estan enviando los datos mediante la url, txtuser seria el dato obtenido de tu edittext al igual que txtpass.